# How to read pdf file on webView From my Local device

Tags: android, webview, pdf-reader

I have two type read 
first :Pdf Read from url OnWebView :Its working
second:Pdf Read from local path OnWebView: dosent working

> (/data/data/com.akfix.navigationdrawer/files/550192f3a1583.pdf)

Second chart isnt working.And i havent any error log.what am i do,

My Pdf reader class here;

```
public class PdfReader extends Activity {
String pdf;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_reader);
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView3);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        pdf = extras.getString("pdfUrl");
        if (extras.getString("catalogPdfUrl") != null) {
            String pdfPath = extras.getString("catalogPdfUrl");

            Uri path = Uri.parse(pdfPath);
            viewPdf(path);

        } else {
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            pdf.replaceAll("\"", "");
            webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
        }
    }


}

private void viewPdf(Uri file) {
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(file, "application/pdf");
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("No Application Found");
        builder.setMessage("Download one from Android Market?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes, Please",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        marketIntent
                                .setData(Uri
                                        .parse("market://details?id=com.adobe.reader"));
                        startActivity(marketIntent);
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No, Thanks", null);
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

}

Help me please.

Comment: since it's local, why you need to display it in a webview?

Comment: because my boss is Want :)

Comment: https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview ,
i've used this library inside my app, it's simply amazing @user3003883

Comment: if it helped you , accept my answer below

Answer (score 2):

since it's local, why you need to display it in a webview?

i've used [this library](http://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview) inside my app, it's simply amazing

Load a PDF file

```
pdfView.fromAsset(pdfName)
.pages(0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3)
.defaultPage(1)
.showMinimap(false)
.enableSwipe(true)
.onDraw(onDrawListener)
.onLoad(onLoadCompleteListener)
.onPageChange(onPageChangeListener)
.load();
```